# With Scrapy, how to get response body behind Ajax as JSON string?

Tags: python, json, soap, response, scrapy

I post here my code to seek for the help, I just want to get response body data as JSON string format as it is, but no luck after many tries.

This data is behind a SOAP Web Service, it isn't normal as XML or HTML format because it loads data in Ajax.

```
# coding: utf8 

import json
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

# C. Crawl Stock Data
class StockSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "stock"

# C1. SSI HOSE
allowed_domains = ["banggia2.ssi.com.vn"]
start_urls = ["http://banggia2.ssi.com.vn/AjaxWebService.asmx/GetHoseIndex"]

def parse(self, response):        
    datas = json.loads(response.body)
    # In Firebug -> Net -> XHR, Response Body is below
    # {"d":"64136@508.68|4.23 (0.84 %)|108210317|1470328|1|136|66|78|K|15:01:17|23/12/2013|1387785677000|0|18:09:17"}

    # Write json data, hope to get the same string like above
    f = open("stock_json_data.txt", "w")
    f.write( str(datas) )
    f.close()              

    # Result:  
    # 2013-12-23 20:40:58+0700 [stock] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://banggia2.ss
    # i.com.vn/AjaxWebService.asmx/GetHoseIndex> (failed 3 times): 500 Internal Server
    # Error
```

Thanks in advance! I will vote up the best answer for you!

[edited] More Information: In .NET I can get these response quite easily, with:

```
   WSTester.AjaxWebService service = new WSTester.AjaxWebService();
   string result = service.GetHoseIndex();
```

Comment: you are deserializing a json string and writing it as a string ? Why not just `json.dumps(response.body)` and write it in a file ?

Comment: If it isn't normal as XML or HTML format, what is it?

Comment: @PepperoniPizza: I have tried json.dumps as you commented, but no luck. Also, I tried to replace start_urls as "http://banggia2.ssi.com.vn/AjaxWebService.asmx?op=GetHoseIndex", but just HTML code. I need to get JSON string as I see in Firebug-Net-XHR.

Comment: @martineau: You can see the URL is: http://banggia2.ssi.com.vn/AjaxWebService.asmx/GetHoseIndex. It's not a .html as normal, as you know if it's XML or HTML I can use XPathSelector to choose nodes base on XPath query in Scrapy.

Comment: for clear: this targeted website is Ajax Website, so I'm facing with technique of how to scrap data of ajax website by using of scrapy opensource

Comment: are you trying to scrap the data and then storing it as Json ?

Comment: @ajkumar25: yes, it is. I'm trying, but no success till now

Answer (score 1):

You can render the output to the `JSON` file by this little command.

```
scrapy crawl <spider_name> -o items.json -t json
```

Refer this guide for more detailed explanations.
http://pypix.com/python/build-website-crawler-based-upon-scrapy/

Comment: No, you don't understand my question here. I'm trouble with scrap website with Ajax behind. I'm studying FormRequest and Selenium to resolve it. Your comment is very easy, haha

Comment: and your URL is very simple, because target website is just HTML, with nodes so that you can traverse by XPath query

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found an solution, which user Scrapy + Selenium to process. This mean I have to do some form submit and capture data in popup window.

Perhaps Scrapy guys should support Ajax Scraping to ease implementation, compare to .NET.